# jQuery .get() not working in a click event function callback

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have been fighting this peculiar problem for quite a few days, to no avail. Since this is freelance work my neck is on the line and I need your help.

Firstly I am creating an app using phonegap and jQuery 1.9.1. The app goes online and gets an itinerary in csv format and keeps it in the app. The jQuery get() function is used for this.

This is where it gets weird. The get function works fine when fired on phonegap's DeviceReady event, like is shown below:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    });
    $.get('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/DavidColson.csv', function(data) {
         alert('Success');
    }, "text")
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An AJAX error occured: " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
     });
 });
},
```

As you can see cross domain pages are allowed and so everything runs smoothly and I get the 'Success' alert.

However if I want this to be called on an event, say when a user clicks on a button, It will not work. Look at this below:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        });

        $("#itineraryAddButton").bind("click", function(event) {
            alert("Event fired");
            $.get('http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/App/DavidColson.csv', function(data) {
                alert('Success');
            }, "text")
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("An AJAX error occured: " + textStatus + "\nError: " + errorThrown);
            });
        });
    },
```

The 'Event fired' alert fires, and then the fail function fires and tells me an ajax error has occured, however the `errorThrown` string is empty, not giving me any clues.

To make it even harder to fix, this only happens when on a physical android device, it works perfectly in a browser and on a virtual android device, making it neraly impossible to debug.

If you would like more information on software versions please tell me, and any other information you would like to help me solve this problem.

David

EDIT:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53792213/itineraryapp.apk
Here is a download link to an unsigned apk to try out. When the app opens click "Add Itinerary" and then a box will appear, what you type in is irrelevant, click "Go get it" to trigger the get() function and watch the alerts.

'Hello' if the event was fired
'Success' if get worked
'An ajax error occured' if it didn't

Comment: Maybe if you can reproduce it in an online environment (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com), even if it only happens in Android devices, we can try to debug it more easily. Also which browser are you using? The droid default? Which droid version?

Comment: It's a standalone app, and so is running in a java webview curtesy of Phonegap/cordova

Comment: could you try to make the get call from `setTimeout(func, 1)` inside `click` handler?

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe a built `.apk` then would at least let us see the error first-hand.

Comment: An APK has been added, tell me what you can see